# Layout System in WPF

Tags: wpf, layout, measureoverride

I want to trigger the Measure/Arrange layout pass of an ItemsControl manually in code behind without user interaction. Is it possible? If yes, How? I tried `InvalidateMeasure()`, `UpdateLayout()`, but no use.

Comment: What is your real problem? Why do you need to trigger the layout management?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`InvalidateVisual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx) method to invoke a re-render:

> Invalidates the rendering of the element, and forces a complete new
>   layout pass. OnRender is called after the layout cycle is completed.

However, as Microsoft recommends that this should scarcely be used manually in applications, there is likely another solution to your problem (such as proper use of dependency properties, for instance), if we knew it.

Comment: Even this not working. Where to call this method? From ItemsControl or from ItemsPanel?

Comment: Please define "not working". What happens? What doesn't happen? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I have a breakpoint in Measure Override of my control's ItemsPanel (say my custom panel). And I am trying the methods as you said in both ItemsControl and ItemsPanel. But breakpoint doesn't hit.